# solr cannot addField, throws undefined method SolrObject::addField()

Tags: php, tomcat, solr

I have a solrobject which I want to add a field.

When I try to addField it throws

```
  PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined method SolrObject::addField()
```

The SolrObject which I get fetch and try to add a field

```
object(SolrObject)#146 (20) {
  ["id"]=>
  string(10) "prof214864"
  ["db_id"]=>
  int(214864)
  ["doc_type"]=>
  string(4) "prof"
}


$doc->addField('age',123);
```

PHP VERSION is 5.3.3

solr-spec 4.3.0

CentOS release 6.5 (

Comment: Of what type is $doc?

Comment: @notdang the object (SolrObject) is assigned to $doc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.solrobject.php, `SolrObject` does not have addField method. 
You need to create a  [SolrDocument](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.solrdocument.php) object and then call `addField` method

Something like this:

```
doc = new SolrDocument();
$doc->addField('id', yourId);
$doc->addField('age',123);
```

Comment: but I want to add field to my current object.